# Cannot get first item of array

Tags: arrays, lua

Here's  an array printed by a function `getTargets();`:

```
{
  name = {
    isPlayer = true,
    isBlocking = false,
    username = "yes"
  }
}
```

When I do `players = getTargets();` to put this in variable and want to access first variable no matter its name, I have some trouble. I tried those:

```
players.name.username --displays "yes"
players[0].username --displays nil
players[1].username --displays nil
```

I want to access first variable of this array no matter what is its value.
**How can I do this?**

Comment: there no array. you can get `players.name.username`.

Comment: @moteus but the "name" can change to something else. How am I supposed to call this then?

Comment: please provide more correct example. Can suggest e.g. `players={ {name = {username = "yes",} } }; print(players[1].name.username`  But not sure is it what you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code

```
local players = {
  name = {
    isPlayer = true,
    isBlocking = false,
    username = "yes"
  }
}
```

is equivalent to

```
local players = {}
players.name = {
  isPlayer = true,
  isBlocking = false,
  username = "yes"
}
```

So there is no index 0 or 1, hence `players[0]` and `players[1]` are nil.
`players[0].username` and `players[1].username` will cause an error for indexing nil values.

To get the first element of a table of unknown keys simply do this:

```
local key, value = next(someTable)
```

https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#pdf-next

> When called with nil as its second argument, next returns an initial
>   index and its associated value.

Keep in mind that:

> The order in which the indices are enumerated is not specified, even
>   for numeric indices.

If you want to make sure you should change your data structures accordingly.
But I cannot give you much advice here as I don't know the purpose of this.

You could have a little function like (simplyfied):

```
local function addPlayerToList(playerList, playerLookUpTable, player)

  table.insert(playerList, player)
  playerLookUpTable[player.name] = #playerList

end
```

Read something about OOP in Lua for nicer and more advanced ideas.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to get the key/name in this way:

```
local players = {
  name = {
    isPlayer = true,
    isBlocking = false,
    username = "yes"
  }
}


local FirstPlayer
for k,v in pairs(players) do FirstPlayer=k break end
print(players[FirstPlayer].username)
```

however there is no guarantee that this will always be the first. But maybe this is your case.

Answer (score 0):

You don't even need a for loop:

```
n,t = pairs(players)
firstKey, firstValue = n(t)
```

https://repl.it/JBw1/1

As lhf pointed out, you don't even need pairs, you can simply do

```
firstKey, firstValue = next(players)
```

Comment: Or simply `firstKey, firstValue = next(players)`. But note that `pairs` and `next` do not guarantee a specific order of traversal. They may give different results in different runs.